# htaccess rule is not applied for creating nice url

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess rule for creating a nice url and for some reason it is not applied.

This is not the first time that I'm creating this kind of rules.
To be sure that I have not made any errors I have run my rules in:
http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php
To see if this create the same one.
and
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
to see it the result is fine.

Both websites give a good feedback. The apache config is correct because I have some other virtual host websites that are using also .htaccess rewrite rules and they are fine.

For privacy reasons I have changed the site name.

The original URL:
`www_site_com/apartments-all.php?group=beach-side`

The rewritten URL:
`www_site_com/group/beach-side.html`

```
RewriteRule ^www_site_com/group/([^/]*)\.html$ /www_site_com/apartments-all.php?group=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What is a ".htaccess rule"? You mean a rewrite rule?

Comment: Sorry, your rule is completely unclear. Your example does _not_ have a string "group", yet your pattern tries to match that. That cannot work. Can it be you confuse "original" and "rewritten"? Or asked otherwise: what do you mean by "original"?

Comment: Supposed you mean the example the other way 'round the rule looks fine to me. In that case either the `.htaccess` style file is not evaluated at all, or your request is different, or you forgot the famous `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: A general hint: since apparently you have access to the host configuration, why do you use `.htaccess` style files? Those files should only be used if there _really_ is no other way. They are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and _really_ slow the server down without need. Put your request rules inside your host configuration instead!

Comment: Right, English is not my language. According to my example I do have a string called group: ?group=beach-side.
RewriteEngine is on.

Comment: is `www_site_com` a directory? Where is your `.htaccess` file stored? What is your document root?

Comment: www_site_com is a directory and the .htaccess is stored there. 
This works 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /www_site_com/apartments-all.php?group=$1 [L]
But I would like to have a fake sub dir. Because I need about 4 different rewrite rules.

Comment: I got it working except that all my relative links are also rewritten.

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^apartments/([^/\.]+)$ www_site_com/apartments-all.php?group=$1 [L]